# Azure Billing scenario issues de-mystified

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have 2 specific scenarios that I can't get out of head regarding billing of windows azure.

*Scenario 1*: If I have 1 instance of say (web role, or work role, or reserved web-site) that sat idle for say 5 hours (by idle i mean no requests or processing or anything at all) will be billed for it? Or am I billed only for when I have activity on it?

*Scenario 2*: Am I billed for the actual size of my database or the size I declared when Ii created it?

This is quite hard to follow up and i would like to thank everyone in advance. Microsoft site is quite unclear and not straightforward about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) each instance is like renting a car. That capacity is reserved for you and you're charged if its parked in the driveway (stopped), being driven in a parade, or cruising down the freeway at 60mph

2) a bit of both. The web and business editions have a minimum size you'll be billed at. But if you declare say a 150gb business Db, but only use 8, you'll only be billed at 10gb (the minimum).

Answer (score 1):

For scenario 1, you are billed based on if the machine is allocated.  So if you setup the machine once and leave it running, as long as it is running you are being billed.  If you are just having a single server that needs to be available 24/7 (even though it might only do work for very short periods during the day), you need to account for about 720 hours per month at the bill rate for that machine size.

For scenario 2, you are billed based on the usages with minimums at certain tiers.  See this document for more info:  http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/#data-management/